# ACF - Query relationship without ID

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

i have different CPT ( hotel, market, city, etc… )

My relationship field is used to link CPT to cities (CITY).

Now in a page ( hotel page ) i want to link “other hotels in same city”.

how can i make my query ? I know how to do a query by ID with the ID of actual page, but what i need is :

$city = get_field(‘contact_city’);
$query = display all hotels with contact_city as $city

But i didn’t find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only 1 value in relation field :

```
$city_id = $bnb_ville[0]->ID;
```

if it could be more than 1 value :

```
$city_id = [];
foreach ($var as $post) {
    $city_id[] = $post->ID;
}
```

$bnb_ville is the variable for get_field() !

Answer (score 0):

Creating query you must use the `meta_query` [parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).
Your *relationship* field is saved in DB as serialized array, 
therefore, in the `meta_query` parameter you should use the `LIKE` operator.

Assuming that the CTP `hotel` has only one `city` assigned, the query would look like this:

```
$cities = get_field('contact_city');
if ( is_array($cities) && count($cities) ) {

    $city_id = current($cities)->ID;
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'hotel',
        'meta_query' => [
            'key'   => 'contact_city',
            'value' => '"' . $city_id . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
        // ...
    ];
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
}
```

If post `hotel` has several `city` assigned, and you want to display links to hotels from all locations assigned to the currently viewed hotel, `meta_query` will change as follows:

```
$args = [
        'post_type' => 'hotel',
        'meta_query' => [
            'relation' => OR,
            [ /* 'key', 'value', 'compare' */ ],
            [ /* 'key', 'value', 'compare' */ ],
        ],
```

**Sample code**:

```
$meta_query = [ 'relation' => 'OR' ];
foreach( $cities as $city )
{
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key'   => 'contact_city',
        'value' => '"' . $city->ID . '"',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ];
}
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'hotel',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
];
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```